# C++ white line skipping error

Tags: c++

This code is part of a "game" that I am developing in Win32:

```
    cout << "You find another deep red apple. Eat or drop?\n";
        cin>>noskipws>>sa;
        while (sa != "Eat"&&sa != "Drop"&&sa != "eat"&&sa != "drop")
        {
            cout << "That's not a valid answer. Please choose from the options you were given." << endl;
            cin >> sa;
        }
```

And then it enters a loop of saying `"That's not a valid answer. Please choose from the options you were given."`

How can make the code work so that it reads the string with white spaces without this occurring? I've tried `getline()` too but it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you mean a string like "eat drop sit stand eat" when you mean a string with white spaces

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about

Comment: @CosminPetolea pls show an example of your expected input / output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do and what kind of input you want to accept. For now I'll guess you want to read strings that contain whitespace in a single call. For that, the easiest way is to use `std::getline()`. You say you tried it and it didn't work, how exactly have you tried it and what didn't work?

Going back to your code, I'll try to explain why it's working the way it does but I won't rewrite it for you, you'll have to try to fix on your own.

Basically the problem is that `std::noskipws` doesn't help you in the way you expect it to. It indeed sets a flag on the stream that causes it to not skip over whitespace characters when reading from it. So you can do something like this for example:

```
char c1, c2, c3;
std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
```

If you run this and enter "a b c" on the input prompt, the values for the three `char`s will be 'a', ' ' (space) and 'b'.

If you instead run:

```
char c1, c2, c3;
std::cin >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
```

the values will be 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

But you're not reading individual characters directly, you're reading an `std::string`. When you do this `std::cin >> someString`, reading WILL stop at the first whitespace character, no matter whether you have that flag set or not. So if you have this:

```
std::cin >> std::noskipws >> sa;
```

and you enter lets say this on the prompt: "not eat or drop". The call above will still read just the first word, "not", into `sa`. The `if` will fail, you will print that message and then try to read again from the stream.

And now the fun part starts. At this point the stream contents look like this: " eat or drop". There is a space at the beginning that doesn't get ignored and skipped because you've set that flag. But now the call to `operator>>()` for strings fails because of that space at the beginning. This sets the `fail` bit on the stream and doesn't read anything. From this moment on, the stream remains in a failed state, every call to `std::cin >> sa` from now on fails instantly and silently and you have an infinite loop that keeps printing that message.

See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for more details on how `operator>>` works for `std::string`s.

### **Later edit**

If when you use `std::getline()` it looks like the first call doesn't wait for input and just returns an empty string immediately, there is an explanation. Check whether somewhere before the call to `getline()` you do any "normal" input from `cin` (using `operator>>`). Let's say before `getline()` you do something like this (not necessarily in the same function):

```
SomeType var;
std::cin >> var;
```

When this asks for input, you probably type something like this on the terminal: `value<ENTER>`. This reads the value but most likely leaves the new line character in the stream. So the first time you call `getline()` after this, it will read and discard the new line character and return (probably an empty string).
One way to get around this problem is to do some cleanup on the stream before calling `getline()`, for example like this:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This basically ignores all leftover characters from previous input and allows you to start with a clean stream.

Comment: I simply replaced cin>>noskipws>>sa; with getline(cin, sa); and it said that it's not a valid answer only once, then it asks for input. If I simply wrote cin>>sa; and typed "la la" as input, it would give me the error two times. I want that error to only occur once

Comment: And by "error" I mean "That's not a valid answer. Please choose from the options you were given."

Comment: I still don't get what the problem is when you use `getline()`. It tells you it's not a valid answer and then it asks for input again. Isn't this what you want? Can you also post the modified code, the version using `getline()`, and what input you provide at each step when you're testing?

Comment: It gives me that error before I type in anything at all

Comment: Are you reading anything else from `std::cin` before that `getline()`?

Comment: See if the edit in the answer helps you fix the problem you're having with `getline`.

Comment: So replace every cin with getline

Comment: Not necessarily, that depends on each case. If you want to read a full line of text or a string containing spaces, then use `getline()`. If you want to read a single string separated by whitespace or you want to read some other data type (`char`, `int` etc), then go with `operator>>` because it's easier. There is no inherent problem in mixing the two, just be aware of how each one works. And also keep in mind the original issue and do some error checking on the stream while reading from it.

Comment: This worked: cout << "You find another deep red apple. Eat or drop?\n";
   getline(cin, sa); getline(cin, sa);
   while (sa != "Eat"&&sa != "Drop"&&sa != "eat"&&sa != "drop")
   {
    cout << "That's not a valid answer. Please choose from the options you were given." << endl;
    getline(cin, sa);
   }

Comment: I didn't know hot to make it look like code, this site is kinda confusing to me XD

Comment: In comments you can use backticks for inline code, the same as in posts. And you can also edit your post and add the code there (but don't change the original question, add it at the end and mark it explicitly as a followup, so the existing answers don't lose their meaning).

Comment: Now regarding your new code, two obvious problems. You're calling `getline()` twice to work around the fact that you have some leftover characters in the stream from previous input, and it may work now, but it's bad style. Maybe later at some point you change how you handle input (maybe in another, unrelated, piece of code, and then there will be no more leftover chars. Then both of those `getline()`s will ask for input and only the second one will actually be used. The second problem is that you still do no error checking on the stream when reading from it.

Comment: Ok problem solved, There was only one "cin>>" and I replaced it with getline() (which I needed at that point anyway) and everything works perfectly fine. I'll keep adding to the game and maybe it will be something more than just a DOS interface Win32 Aplication someday

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trim the input string, you can use the boost string algorithms, see the example [here](https://ideone.com/COvz0C)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main() {
    string sa;
    while (std::getline(cin, sa)) {
        boost::trim(sa);       // remove leading & trailing whitespace
        if (sa == "Eat" || sa == "Drop" || sa == "eat" || sa == "drop") {
            std::cout << "Option was " << sa << std::endl;
            break;
        } 
        std::cout << "That's not a valid answer." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input (some spaces at begining of line):

```
   WrongInput
     Eat
```

Output:

```
That's not a valid answer. Please choose from the options you were given.
Option was Eat
```

Comment: @CosminPetolea uh, so was this helpful or not? you can revise the question or leave a comment if you were looking for smth else?

Answer (score 0):

There is a little coding involved, replace your while loop with a do-while loop, and use string find function to search for you word. 
Next there is the piece of code that could solve your issue, give it a try and rate it if it's good to you.

```
string sa;
cout << "You find another deep red apple. Eat or drop?\n";
getline(cin, sa);
bool wordFound = false;
do
{       
    if (sa.find("Eat") != std::string::npos ||
        sa.find("Drop") != std::string::npos ||
        sa.find("eat") != std::string::npos ||
        sa.find("drop") != std::string::npos)
    {
        wordFound = true;
    }

    if (wordFound == false)
    {
        cout << "That's not a valid answer. Please choose from the options you were given." << endl;
        cin >> sa;
    }
} while (!wordFound);
```